# Getting 404 error when making WMS call on GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api, tomcat

I am trying to make a WMS call to GeoServer with parameters to get a specific layer. However, when my application makes a WMS call to GeoServer, I am getting a 404 error in the console and the network calls..

In the logs for Tomcat, every time I try to make a WMS call, the following error pops up: `02 Sep 15:40:05 WARN [servlet.PageNotFound] - No mapping for GET /geoserver/workspace/wms`

Not sure why I am getting this error.

Example of my WMS call:
`Request URL: http://<domain>:<port>/geoserver/<workspace>/wms?service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=<workspace><layername>&styles=&format=image%2Fpng8&transparent=true&version=1.1.0&icon=symbol&tiled=true&height=512&width=512&srs=EPSG%3A3857&bbox=-10018754.171394622,0,-7514065.628545968,2504688.542848655`

Comment: cross-posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63714492/getting-404-error-when-making-wms-call-on-geoserver

Comment: Do you have any security restrictions on the workspace, that would make the workspace invisible to the user making the request? (eventually, the anonymous one)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I didn't have any of the Services checked in my workspace, which is why I was unable to make any WMS calls! Thank you Andrea Aime for the help!

Answer (score 6):

A colon `:` between the workspace and the layer is missing. If the layer exists in the provided workspace, the URL below should work:

```
  Request URL: http://<domain>:<port>/geoserver/<workspace>/wms?service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=<workspace>:<layername>&styles=&format=image%2Fpng8&transparent=true&version=1.1.0&icon=symbol&tiled=true&height=512&width=512&srs=EPSG%3A3857&bbox=-10018754.171394622,0,-7514065.628545968,2504688.542848655
```